# using generics with xml deserialisation

Tags: c#, generics, xml-serialization

I want to pass an object into the resulting type of an xml deserialisation and maintain strong typing.

So the deserialisation class can take any type that implements the IResult interface which in this case is Result and Result2.

I have got this working by making the getObject method return dynamic but i would much rather keep the compile time checking and i think it should be possible.

I have tried using generics, as in the example below, but the deser.getObject(doc()); line gives me a "cannot be inferred from usage" compile error.

Thanks for all help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace SOQuestion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var deser = new Deserialised(new Result());
            var result = deser.getObject(doc());

            var deser2 = new Deserialised(new Result2());
            var result2 = deser.getObject(doc());

            Console.Writeline(result.status);
            Console.Writeline(result2.status);
        }

        public XmlDocument doc()
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            var el = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Result"));
            el.SetAttribute("status", "ok");
            el.SetAttribute("status2", "not ok");
            return doc;

        }

    }

    class Deserialised
    {

        private IResult result;
        private Type resultType;

        public Deserialised(IResult _result)
        {
            result = _result;
            resultType = Type.GetType(result.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);
        }


        public T getObject<T>(XmlDocument xml)
        {
            var mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(resultType);
            var myStream = new MemoryStream();
            xml.Save(myStream);
            myStream.Position = 0;
            var r = mySerializer.Deserialize(myStream);
            return (T)r;
        }

    }

    interface IResult
    {
        public string status {get;set;}
    }



    [Serializable]
    public class Result :IResult
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Result2 : IResult
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string status2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you think it should be getting the `<T>` from? if you were doing it manually, how would *you* know the `T`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So i have found a solution that my two requirements of 1. that passed in type implements IResult interface 2. that the returned object is statically typed.
A generic method with a constraint like below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace SOQuestion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var result = new Deserialised().getObject<Result>();

            var result2 = new Deserialised().getObject<Result2>();

            Console.WriteLine(result.status);
            Console.WriteLine(result.errorMessage);
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }

    class Deserialised
    {

        public T getObject<T>() where T : IResult
        {
            try
            {
                var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                var mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(instance.GetType());
                var myStream = new MemoryStream();
                doc().Save(myStream);
                myStream.Position = 0;
                var r = mySerializer.Deserialize(myStream);
                throw new DivideByZeroException();
                return (T)r;
            }

            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                instance.errorMessage = "something wrong here";
                return instance;
            }
            ;
        }

    public static XmlDocument doc()
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            var el = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Result"));
            el.SetAttribute("status", "ok");
            el.SetAttribute("status2", "notok");
            return doc;

        }

    }

    interface IResult
    {
        string status { get; set; }
        string errorMessage { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Result : IResult
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string status { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string errorMessage { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string message { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Result2 : IResult
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string status { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string message2 { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string errorMessage { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Result3
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string status { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string message2 { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string errorMessage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You use `Activator.CreateInstance<T>();` just in order to call `GetType()` on it? Just use `typeof( T )`.

Comment: ... and what is up with the `DivideByZeroException`? You will always return _"something wrong here"_ this way.

Comment: divide by zero was in the test the catch block

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, that isn't going to work - the compiler has no way of knowing the `T` from that. Remember that the `T` comes from the *caller at compile-time*, not from the result of the method at runtime. There *are* ways to switch between reflection/generics, but it is ugly and isn't going to help much here. I would just return `object` instead:

```
public object GetObject(XmlDocument xml) {
    var mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(resultType);
    using(var myStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        xml.Save(myStream);
        myStream.Position = 0;
        return mySerializer.Deserialize(myStream);
    }
}
```

and then let the caller handle the `dynamic` etc:

```
var deser = new Deserialised(new Result());
dynamic result = deser.GetObject(doc());

var deser2 = new Deserialised(new Result2());
dynamic result2 = deser.GetObject(doc());

Console.Writeline(result.status);
Console.Writeline(result2.status);
```

Because of the `dynamic` above, the `.status` in the two `Console.WriteLine` will still work.

Comment: But this doesn't help as I want compile time checking in the calling method. Also, the deserialised class does know the type at compile time as it is passed into the the constructor which is then used to set the resultType variable in the XmlSerialiser. Does it change anything if i pass the Result object into getObject as a generic parameter rather than getting it from the private field?

Comment: @Jules yes, that would give it something to infer the `T` from, but the passed-in instance would (I suspect) be entirely redundant, since the serializer is going to create the actual instance.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion [the answer you provided yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13250802/590790) overcomplicates things. (In addition to doing some other weird stuff, ... see my comment.)

There is nothing gained in using generics here. You can just as well use the following approach, and both of your requirements will still hold.

```
public IResult GetObject(XmlDocument xml)
{
    var mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(resultType);
    using (var myStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        xml.Save(myStream);
        myStream.Position = 0;
        return (IResult)mySerializer.Deserialize(myStream);
    }
}
```

... simply call it as follows:

```
var deser = new Deserialised(new Result());
var result = (Result)deser.getObject(doc());

var deser2 = new Deserialised(new Result2());
var result2 = (Result2)deser.getObject(doc());
```

Casting to anything which doesn't implement `IResult` will trigger a compiler error.

---

It is not really clear what you are trying to do here, but suppose you made `Deserialised` generic.

```
class Deserialised<T>
    where T : IResult
{

    private T result;
    private Type resultType;

    public Deserialised(T _result)
    {
        result = _result;
    }


    public T getObject(XmlDocument xml)
    {
        var mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var myStream = new MemoryStream();
        xml.Save(myStream);
        myStream.Position = 0;
        var r = (T)mySerializer.Deserialize(myStream);
        return r;
    }

}
```

Why are you even passing `_result` as a parameter and storing it? My guess is you only needed it since you didn't know about `typeof()`? In that case simply drop it. After doing so again you just end up with a class which defines your generic parameter, with again the sole purpose to define the required cast.

Comment: yes, just seems a bit ugly that you have to cast the result when the Deserialised class should be able to know the type you want from the constructor parameter. Any ideas how i might be able to remove this cast?

Comment: @Jules A few notes will follow later, but first: what is uglier about the cast than specifying a generic parameter? The only thing the generic does for you is do the cast inside the method instead of outside. There is nothing inherently 'generic' about it, hence I find using a generic approach not to be clearer at all. It's the same amount of code.

Comment: You do have a point, and as you seem to only want to use the `Deserialised` class for `IResult` objects, you can easily make `Deserialised` generic. I will update my answer.

Comment: Hopefully the update makes some sense. It seems like you are jumping through a lot of unnecessary loopholes just in order to not do a cast. If you _know_ a cast won't fail, just do the cast, and you can continue statically typed from there.